# Добавление class

Tags: классы, link, ul

Есть такой список в котором при выборе пункта переводит на другую страницу. Задача что бы при переходе на другую страницу в пункте меню оставался выбраный пункт.

```js
$.fn.ulSelect = function() {
  var ul = $(this);

  if (!ul.hasClass('zg-ul-select')) {
    ul.addClass('zg-ul-select');
  }
  // SVG arrow
  var arrow = '<svg id="ul-arrow" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><line stroke-width="1" x1="" y1="" x2="" y2="" stroke="#449FDB" opacity=""/><path d="M4.131 8.962c-0.434-0.429-1.134-0.429-1.566 0-0.432 0.427-0.432 1.122 0 1.55l12.653 12.528c0.434 0.429 1.133 0.429 1.566 0l12.653-12.528c0.432-0.429 0.434-1.122 0-1.55s-1.136-0.429-1.566-0.002l-11.87 11.426-11.869-11.424z" fill="#111"/></svg>';
  $('li:first-of-type', this).addClass('active').append(arrow);
  $(this).on('click', 'li', function(event) {

    // Remove div#selected if it exists
    if ($('#selected--zg-ul-select').length) {
      $('#selected--zg-ul-select').remove();
    }
    ul.before('<div id="selected--zg-ul-select">');
    var selected = $('#selected--zg-ul-select');
    $('li #ul-arrow', ul).remove();
    ul.toggleClass('active');
    // Remove active class from any <li> that has it...
    ul.children().removeClass('active');
    // And add the class to the <li> that gets clicked
    $(this).toggleClass('active');

    var selectedText = $(this).text();
    if (ul.hasClass('active')) {
      selected.text(selectedText).addClass('active').append(arrow);
    } else {
      selected.text('').removeClass('active');
      $('li.active', ul).append(arrow);
    }
  });

  $(document).on('click', function(event) {
    if ($('ul.zg-ul-select').length) {
      if (!$('ul.zg-ul-select').has(event.target).length == 0) {
        return;
      } else {
        $('ul.zg-ul-select').removeClass('active');
        $('#selected--zg-ul-select').removeClass('active').text('');
        $('#ul-arrow').remove();
        $('ul.zg-ul-select li.active').append(arrow);
      }
    }
  });
}

// Run
$('#be-select').ulSelect();
```

```css
ul.zg-ul-select {
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.zg-ul-select li {
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: none;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

ul.zg-ul-select li.active {
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #111;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #aaa;
  color: #111;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

ul.zg-ul-select.active {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

ul.zg-ul-select.active li {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: block;
}

ul.zg-ul-select.active li:hover {
  background: #0074d9;
}

ul.zg-ul-select.active li.active {
  background: #40a6ff;
}

ul.zg-ul-select.active li.active:hover {
  background: #0074d9;
}

#selected--zg-ul-select {
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #111;
  display: flex;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 2em;
  width: auto;
}

#selected--zg-ul-select.active {
  border: 1px solid #111;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #aaa;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="be-select" tabindex="0">
  <li>
    <a href="/cabinet/employees/" class="active">
      <i class="material-icons"></i> Работники </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/cabinet/company-register/">
      <i class="material-icons"></i> Сompany register </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/cabinet/orders/">
      <i class="material-icons"></i> User orders </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Я нашел вот такой скрипт, который добавляет class="active" к нужному пункту, но добавляет его для Линки, а не для LI.

```js
var url_keyword = window.location.pathname.split('/')[3]
$('.cabinet-menu-min li a[href*="/' + url_keyword + '/"]').addClass('active')
```

Помогите Добавить класс в LI и еще при выборе пункта, если нажать на верхний  линк (тот который к боксе) , то он сразу срабатывает, как сделать его не активным?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Теперь по-идее он добавляет класс вашему Ли. Типа он нашел ваш Линк, потом смотри на его родителя Ли, и добавляет класс ему. Ответ вам подходит?

```js
var url_keyword = window.location.pathname.split('/')[3]
$('.cabinet-menu-min li a[href*="/' + url_keyword + '/"]').parent().addClass('active')
```

Comment: Да спасибо) class добавляет верно)

Comment: Поставьте галочку ответу, чтоб в будущем другие пользователи могли ориентироваться в вашем вопросе.